# gv$session count in query block

Tags: sql, plsql

I am looking forward to have a simple PL/SQL block which will query the gv$session for a particular condition and paste the count of it in a temporary table along with the timestamp.I want the query to run every 1 minute.

For example the query will be like this `select count(*) from gv$session where ID='1'` 
and the output of this should be pasted in some table along with the timestamp for which it is executing.
the query should run every 1 minute till we stop it manually

Comment: I tried insert into tables using select statement but along with timestamp I am unable to proceed..also to put it in a plsql block.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's pretty hard to understand without the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable
    (
       id            INTEGER
     , cnt           INTEGER
     , modified_dt   DATE
    );

    CREATE TRIGGER mytable_t1
       BEFORE INSERT
       ON mytable
       FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       :new.modified_dt   := SYSDATE;
    END;

    INSERT INTO mytable (
                   id, cnt
                )
         VALUES (1, 100);
    END:
```

Comment: I am looking forward for the following in the procedure.1)select count(*) from gv$session where ID='1' should ne queried every 5mts 2)the count(*) along with the date and timestamp should be inserted in a temp table.I am looking for a procedure which can do this both.3)the procedure should stop after every 1hr.